# Sending 2D data from host to device in openCL

Tags: opencl

Can I send 2 dimensional data to device? If yes then how can I do that? Means how will be the declaration of the buffer memory? And also how can I fetch/ use these values in kernel function/device?

Comment: "*Plz reply ASAP*" - No.

Answer (score 2):

> Plz reply ASAP

Sure.

A `cl_mem` object can not contain other `cl_mem` objects. Thus, it is not possible to use "2D" data like this in OpenCL. (In CUDA, this is possible, because the "buffers" there are only pointers to device memory).

Usually, you can convert your data into *one* large `cl_mem` object and access it appropriately in the kernel:

```
__kernel void compute(__global float *data2D, int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    int ix = get_global_id(0);        
    int iy = get_global_id(1);
    int index = ix + iy * sizeX;
    float element = data2D[index];
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a 2D buffer in C++ side.

```
 a Buffer of type (float *)[2048];
```

Then you need to get address of that buffer by

```
 float *address= &a[0][0];
```

Then you use that address for you cl_mem object.

You can use stack too!

```
 float *a=new float[2048][2048];
 ....
 ....
 float *address=&a[0][0];
```

Your opencl-side access to this area must be overlapping exactly to C++ side. Other than C++, you need to know if your matrices are row-major or colum-major or if its being array of arrays or array of objects(like java) before playing with them. If your matrix is not continuous on memory, it can fail.

There are functions to WRITE or READ to/from your buffers from/to opencl buffers. Their structure and wrappers can change from version to version (or even the language that being used in)